# Restriction list and the reputation required to bypass restriction

Tags: discussion

is there an "official" list of restrictions and the reputation required to bypass those restrictions?
I'm a new user, and I am encountering quite a few restrictions.
For example, I cannot post within 25 minutes of a preceding post after I've written out a lengthy sum of words.  I wish I would have known that before I took the time to write it out.

Comment: It's a bit more positive than you make it out to be. There are no "restrictions" that you "bypass". There are **priveleges** that you **earn**. Mouse over the triangle next to your username at the top of the page, and then click "priveleges" to read all about them.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) page.

It will show you all the existing privileges and how much reputation is needed for them.

You will find a link from the account summary drop down:

[image: privileges]